# Java: Write to OutputStream and then use it as InputStream

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, outputstream

I want to get a file from a remote storage as an InputStream without saving it to the local File System. The remote storage provides a Java API with a method that takes an OutputStream and dumps the file data into it.

```
void dump(OutputStream dest);
```

The easy way I've come up with is to create a temporary file, dump the data into it and reopen it as an InputStream. But this approach creates a temporary file. Is there an easy way to achieve the same result without a proxy file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options:

#### Memory

If the "file" in question is small enough for it to be viable, you could read the data into a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), and then use its [`toByteArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray--) method to construct a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) to read from.

#### Piping

To avoid storing more in memory than necessary, you could use [`PipedOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) and [`PipedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html).

`PipedOutputStream`:

> A piped output stream can be connected to a piped input stream to create a communications pipe. The piped output stream is the sending end of the pipe. Typically, data is written to a `PipedOutputStream` object by one thread and data is read from the connected `PipedInputStream` by some other thread.

`PipedInputStream`:

> A piped input stream should be connected to a piped output stream; the piped input stream then provides whatever data bytes are written to the piped output stream. Typically, data is read from a PipedInputStream object by one thread and data is written to the corresponding PipedOutputStream by some other thread.

You give the API the output stream, and read from the input stream.